# Compare Machine Score and Human Score using R

Tags: r, natural-language

This is a part of my research work. I have collected three human raters scores for an essay question(N=54). I am building Automated Scoring Algorithm. So I need to compare my machine score with the Human rater score. All are using 0-10 rating scale. For example;

```
| H1 | H2 | H3 | Adj | Diff | Sys_Score |
  2    5    4    4.5    -1      5
  3    7    9      8     2      9
  8    7    4    7.5    -3      6
```

- `H1,H2,H3` = are human raters' scores
- `Adj` = I calculated
  correlation(R) between H1~H2, H1~H3 and H2~H3, and found that H2~H3
  is highly correlated compared to others. So I calculate Adj =
  Average(H2,H3); except If the difference between these two variables
  (H2,H3) is higher than > 1, then I consider other variable(H1).
- `Diff` = the difference between H2 and H3(correlated pair)
- `SysScore`= System Output

**My question are,**

1. How to compare the Human Score and Machine score using R ?
2. Is it the best way? How to derive the True score from the Human Rater's score?

Comment: those seem more like questions for you than us

Comment: You should read the help pages for SO and see what is on-topic (and not). There are other forums where this would be on-topic.

Comment: Do you consider all three human experts equally good? (I.e. do you have any prior knowledge of the expected relative quality of their scoring?)

Comment: @DarrenCook Yes, we are using demonstrators of the uni, who do the actual marking, so they have prior experiences. One thing is that is it justifiable number of Human rater we used to make a argument that it consists less human error when deriving `Adj`. Is there any statistical justification of finding difference those exceeds 1?

Comment: Whether human raters of essays are truly capable of providing an objective 'gold standard' against which to assess your machine score is debatable. It may interest you to read the 3rd section of the latest [Visual Revelations column](http://chance.amstat.org/2014/09/changes-in-the-sat/) (Sep 2014).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you only have three human experts, I would not worry about the true score and instead I would evaluate your machine score three times: first against H1, second against H2, third against H3.

To evaluate, I think the difference squared (i.e. MSE) is fine. So, average the MSE against each of H1, H2 and H3, to get an evaluation of the quality of your machine score. The lower the number the better.

If you are not trying to compare/optimize multiple machine algorithms, and instead only have a single system to evaluate, and you simply want to get a feel for "is it good or not", then you could do the same evaluation for the humans, i.e. H1 against H2 and H3, H2 against H1 and H3, and H3 against H1 and H2. If your average MSE is higher than all of H1, H2 and H3, it suggests your algorithm is not so good.

All this suffers a bit from only having three human experts, who (judging by the three rows you showed) do not agree among themselves very well. Every human expert you can add will increase the accuracy of your conclusions.

Comment: finally an acceptable answer. Thank you very much for your directions and suggestions :)